# Issues with SQL Server MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, merge

Source Table

```
Id, Name, Address
1   A     #202
1   A     #203
1   A     #204
2   A     #202
```

Target Table

```
Id, Name, Address
1   A     NULL
```

After Merge

```
Id, Name, Address
1   A     #202
2   A     #202
```

I am using this SQL

```
create table #S   (ID int, Name varchar(25) NULL, Address varchar(25) NULL)
create table #T   (ID int, Name varchar(25) NULL, Address varchar(25) NULL)

 INSERT #S values(1, 'A', '#202')
 INSERT #S values(1, 'A', '#203')
 INSERT #S values(1, 'A', '#203')
 INSERT #S values(1, 'A', '#204')

 INSERT #T values(1, 'A', NULL)

 MERGE #T USING
  (
Select id, name, address 
from #S
  ) AS S(id,name,address)
 on #T.id=S.id and #T.Name=S.Name
 when not matched THEN
    INSERT values(S.id,S.Name, S.Address)
 when matched then
    update set Address = S.Address;
 GO 

 Select * from #T
 GO 

 Select * from #S
 GO
```

This causes an error

> Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

I want to update the row in A with Address value from any of the three matching values. How to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Any of the four values in `#S` will match your target table's single row value (all values in #S have id = 1 and name = 'A' - so they all match the single row in the target), thus this value will be updated four times - that's what the error says, and it's absolutely right.

What is it you really want to achieve here??

Do you want to set the Address to the first of the values from the source table? Use a `TOP 1` clause in your subselect:

```
MERGE #T 
USING (SELECT TOP 1 id, name, address FROM #S) AS S
ON #T.id = S.id AND #T.Name = S.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(S.id,S.Name, S.Address)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Address = S.Address;
```

Do you want to set the Address to a random element of the values from the source table? Use a `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY NEWID()` clause in your subselect:

```
MERGE #T 
USING (SELECT TOP 1 id, name, address FROM #S ORDER BY NEWID()) AS S
ON #T.id = S.id AND #T.Name = S.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(S.id,S.Name, S.Address)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Address = S.Address;
```

If you match four source rows to a single target row, you'll never get a useful result - you need to know what you really want.

Marc

Comment: I want to update the row in A with Address value from any of the three matching values

Comment: but how do you determine which of them to use?

Comment: I used Row_Number is both the source and target(view) . Then matching criteria included additional condition, if rownumbers are equal along with ( target.address isnull or (t.address = s.address))

Comment: @marc i have the same issue, but with extra requirement. I want to update the last value coming from the source and also my source table include another field street that it values will be s1,s2,s3,s4. and i want to grape this result after the update is finished A s1, A s2, A s3, A s4 to use this data in another update stament. Any Idea ?

Comment: This does not work for all cases. If the source is having audit log information which you need to port into the destination , how would picking up a single row works?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dupicate using

```
select R.* 
from  (SELECT Customer,Material,Received_date_time,
row_number() over (Partition by Customer, Material   
order by  Customer,Material,Received_date_time) as rn
      from Customer_Table WHERE Status=0     
     ) as R
where R.rn = 1
```

for merge you cannot have duplicates, so you always have to pick up the latest

Comment: Depending on the case, this makes more sense. Maybe you can add a unique constraint.