# Error message having to do with merge, but it's not a merge

Tags: php, sql

I'm getting the error message 
    "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once."

when we run our code.  I'm surprised we would get that error message since the code is not doing a merge.  This is the code:

```
$qry = 'SELECT "PrintSamples"."PrintSampleID", "PrintSamples"."TestPatternName", "PrintSamples"."PrintCopyID", 
"DigitalImages"."CaptureTime", "PrintSampleAnalyses"."psaTicket", "Measurements"."MeasurementID", "Measurements"."MeasurementUuid", 
SUBSTRING("OperatorLastName",1,1) AS "lastInitial", SUBSTRING("OperatorFirstName",1,1) AS "firstInitial",
"ParameterValues"."ParameterID", "ParameterName", "TargetName", "ParameterValues"."ParameterValue"
FROM "ParameterValues"
LEFT JOIN "Measurements" ON "ParameterValues"."MeasurementID"="Measurements"."MeasurementID" 
LEFT JOIN "PrintSampleAnalyses" ON "PrintSampleAnalyses"."psaID"="Measurements"."psaID"
LEFT JOIN "DigitalImages" ON "DigitalImages"."ImageID"="PrintSampleAnalyses"."ImageID" 
LEFT JOIN "PrintSamples" ON "DigitalImages"."PrintSampleID"="PrintSamples"."PrintSampleID"
LEFT JOIN "Sessions" ON "Sessions"."SessionID"="PrintSampleAnalyses"."SessionID" 
LEFT JOIN "Operators" ON "Operators"."OperatorID"="Sessions"."OperatorID"
LEFT JOIN "ParameterNames" ON "ParameterNames"."ParameterID"="ParameterValues"."ParameterID"
LEFT JOIN "Targets" ON "Targets"."TargetID"="Measurements"."TargetID"
WHERE ('; 
// this list comes from the "MeasurementNames" table

foreach ($measurementIDs as $mid){
    if($mid[0] == "AvgGhostValAsSir77") $qry .= '(("ParameterName" LIKE ' . "'%AvgGhostValAsSir77%'" . ') AND ("TargetName"=' . "'" . $mid[1] . "')) OR "; 
    else if($mid[0] == "MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77") $qry .= '(("ParameterName" LIKE ' . "'%MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77%'" . ') AND ("TargetName"=' . "'" . $mid[1] . "')) OR "; 
    else $qry .= '(("ParameterName"=' . "'" . $mid[0] . "'" . ') AND ("TargetName"=' . "'" . $mid[1] . "')) OR ";
}    
$qry = substr ($qry, 0, -4);
$qry .= ") ";

$qry .= ' AND ("ParameterValues"."ParameterValue" != -99999) ORDER BY "PrintSampleID", "MeasurementID"';

dataLog("Start pq query");

$result = pg_query ($pg_conn, $qry);
```

When I look at the code, I'm not seeing any repeats, but it shouldn't be having the error message in the first place because it's not a merge.

The following is the beginning of the error message:

> "    SELECT "PrintSamples"."PrintSampleID",
>   "PrintSamples"."TestPatternName", "PrintSamples"."PrintCopyID",
>   "DigitalImages"."CaptureTime", "PrintSampleAnalyses"."psaTicket",
>   "Measurements"."MeasurementID", "Measurements"."MeasurementUuid",
>   SUBSTRING("OperatorLastName",1,1) AS "lastInitial",
>   SUBSTRING("OperatorFirstName",1,1) AS "firstInitial",
>   "ParameterValues"."ParameterID", "ParameterName", "TargetName",
>   "ParameterValues"."ParameterValue" FROM "ParameterValues" LEFT JOIN
>   "Measurements" ON
>   "ParameterValues"."MeasurementID"="Measurements"."MeasurementID" LEFT
>   JOIN "PrintSampleAnalyses" ON
>   "PrintSampleAnalyses"."psaID"="Measurements"."psaID" LEFT JOIN
>   "DigitalImages" ON
>   "DigitalImages"."ImageID"="PrintSampleAnalyses"."ImageID" LEFT JOIN
>   "PrintSamples" ON
>   "DigitalImages"."PrintSampleID"="PrintSamples"."PrintSampleID" LEFT
>   JOIN "Sessions" ON
>   "Sessions"."SessionID"="PrintSampleAnalyses"."SessionID" LEFT JOIN
>   "Operators" ON "Operators"."OperatorID"="Sessions"."OperatorID" LEFT
>   JOIN "ParameterNames" ON
>   "ParameterNames"."ParameterID"="ParameterValues"."ParameterID" LEFT
>   JOIN "Targets" ON "Targets"."TargetID"="Measurements"."TargetID" WHERE
>   ((("ParameterName"='MeanLs') AND ("TargetName"='Background.BL')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='MeanLs') AND ("TargetName"='S3.005')) OR  ..."

The following is part of what we see for the end of the error message:
"...

> ("TargetName"='Rogum')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='1.0_AveOfAve_DensityAs938') AND 
>   ("TargetName"='Rogum')) OR (("ParameterName" LIKE
>   '%AvgGhostValAsSir77%') AND ("TargetName"='HalfToneArea')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='GhostingAmplitude') AND
>   ("TargetName"='HalfToneArea')) OR (("ParameterName" LIKE
>   '%MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77%') AND ("TargetName"='HalfToneArea')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='MaxPosGhostingValAsSir77') AND
>   ("TargetName"='HalfToneArea')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9h.1;pos#1')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9h.1;pos#5')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9h.1;pos#9')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9v.1;pos#1')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9v.1;pos#5')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9v.1;pos#9')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9h.1;neg#1')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9h.1;neg#5')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9h.1;neg#9')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9v.1;neg#1')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9v.1;neg#5')) OR (("ParameterName"='widthA') AND
>   ("TargetName"='S9v.1;neg#9')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.Y020')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.Y040')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.Y100')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.M020')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.M040')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.M100')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.C020')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.C040')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.C100')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.K020')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.K040')) OR (("ParameterName"='NMF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.K100')) OR (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.Y020')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF') AND ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.Y040'))
>   OR (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.M020')) OR (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.M040')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF') AND ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.C020'))
>   OR (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.C040')) OR (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.K020')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='VisualNoiseHF') AND ("TargetName"='FF.16x16.K040'))
>   OR (("ParameterName"='VBSHorizontal') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.Y050')) OR (("ParameterName"='VBSVertical')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.Y050')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='VBSHorizontal') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.M050')) OR (("ParameterName"='VBSVertical')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.M050')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='VBSHorizontal') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.C050')) OR (("ParameterName"='VBSVertical')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.C050')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='VBSHorizontal') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.K050')) OR (("ParameterName"='VBSVertical')
>   AND ("TargetName"='FF.196x214.K050')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.Y020')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.Y040')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.Y100')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.M020')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.M040')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.M100')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.C020')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.C040')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.C100')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.K020')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.K040')) OR
>   (("ParameterName"='Mottle_as_SIR71_G-Level') AND
>   ("TargetName"='FF.80x80.K100')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sv.010')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST2') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sv.010')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sh.010')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST2') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sh.010')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sv.030')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST2') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sv.030')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sh.030')) OR (("ParameterName"='HDST2') AND
>   ("TargetName"='T40Sh.030'))) AND ("ParameterValues"."ParameterValue"
>   != -99999) ORDER BY "PrintSampleID", "MeasurementID"

All I can think of is that our GhostingAmplitude is being interpreted the same as the statements that use "like".  From what I've read about the like statement, it shouldn't be doing that.  It still doesn't explain why this is getting an error message that talks about merge.

I've read the following about this recently:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434028/problem-with-sql-merge-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09t6a82%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09t6a82%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Check that the qry string actually contains what you think it does. Make sure it starts with SELECT.

Comment: It contains select.  I see it at the start of the error message output.

Comment: How long is the SQL string? How many characters? Does the error message show the whole SQL string?

Comment: Yes, the error message shows entire sql string. When I copy the string to word, it says the character count with spaces is 6708.

Comment: I'm looking at this link <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx> and they say the max number of columns in a select is 4096, but I'm not sure how they define a column.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: @PeteR - I know, it's not pretty.  It's an OLAP database and that doesn't help I'm sure.  Plus a lot of ugly data.

Comment: I've got the theory that the SQL is larger than some system-set limit, and the sql string is being truncated giving a nonsense statement which is being interpreted as something that it isn't. Trying to find the max size of a sql query lead to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet seems to imply that the default max is 4096, and your 6.7k would break that, although following that link it becomes a bit unclear. Something to look at, though.

Comment: Hold on: is the SQL Server or MySQL? I've been assuming (due to php) that it's MySQL. And you say it's OLAP?

Comment: @simon at rcl - it's SQL, not MySQL.

Comment: Try the SQL Profiler and check what SQL it is actually trying to run.

Comment: @simonatrcl - Can the profiler be used with sql 2008 R2?

Comment: I added print statements to the php and it looks like the error message isn't from the select/where statement.  It's later in the code...a merge source/target statement.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to look at the data in temp tables to see if it's good before it tries to merge, or what it's merging. We thought it was the select/where above because it was printing an incorrect query for where the error was happening.

Comment: I'm assuming we're starting new thread because of left turn. Thanks for the help! <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413053/merge-statement-temporary-table-how-to-direct-data-into-a-local-array>