# merge statement temporary table - how to direct data into a local array?

Tags: php, sql, merge, olap

We're having a tough time debugging because our retired predecessor has a query statement that puts pulled data into a series of temporary tables before uploading to the database.  It's not working now (we added items to TestPatterns table, and running for tp7 instead of tp21 so data may differ) and we're having a tough time debugging it.  If we could somehow print or access the data put in the temporary tables, maybe we could debug it better.  Any ideas on how to debug this better, and maybe see the data? We can print our first select/where statement, but not the data it pulls when the qry is executed. Plus there's the Source/Target sql merges we do.  **We know everything seems to work until we execute the $qry1d.**

I looked online for how to view this info, and see the sql profiler, but I'm worried the statements are too complex to decipher the profiler output.  When I tried to profile withhttp://youtu.be/mJ8Dyv4Uk6E, for a simple select top 1000 rows, it said:

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
clmns.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tbl.object_id
WHERE
(CAST(clmns.is_sparse AS bit)=@_msparam_0)and((tbl.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_2))
ORDER BY
clmns.column_id ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'0',@_msparam_1=N'Measurements',@_msparam_2=N'dbo'
```

It's failing with

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

This is a couple of the php sql merge statements:

```
$qry = 'SELECT "PrintSamples"."PrintSampleID", "PrintSamples"."TestPatternName", "PrintSamples"."PrintCopyID", 
"DigitalImages"."CaptureTime", "PrintSampleAnalyses"."psaTicket", "Measurements"."MeasurementID", "Measurements"."MeasurementUuid", 
SUBSTRING("OperatorLastName",1,1) AS "lastInitial", SUBSTRING("OperatorFirstName",1,1) AS "firstInitial",
"ParameterValues"."ParameterID", "ParameterName", "TargetName", "ParameterValues"."ParameterValue"
FROM "ParameterValues"
LEFT JOIN "Measurements" ON "ParameterValues"."MeasurementID"="Measurements"."MeasurementID" 
LEFT JOIN "PrintSampleAnalyses" ON "PrintSampleAnalyses"."psaID"="Measurements"."psaID"
LEFT JOIN "DigitalImages" ON "DigitalImages"."ImageID"="PrintSampleAnalyses"."ImageID" 
LEFT JOIN "PrintSamples" ON "DigitalImages"."PrintSampleID"="PrintSamples"."PrintSampleID"
LEFT JOIN "Sessions" ON "Sessions"."SessionID"="PrintSampleAnalyses"."SessionID" 
LEFT JOIN "Operators" ON "Operators"."OperatorID"="Sessions"."OperatorID"
LEFT JOIN "ParameterNames" ON "ParameterNames"."ParameterID"="ParameterValues"."ParameterID"
LEFT JOIN "Targets" ON "Targets"."TargetID"="Measurements"."TargetID"
WHERE ('; 

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The two statements where added to make AvgGhostValAsSir77 and MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77 work.
// After much testing it was found that the query did not recognize these to ParameterNames in the 
// Postgres database. It was never discovered why when testing the ParameterName to be equal to
// AvgGhostValAsSir77 or MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77 the query fails but using the LIKE statement 
// corrected the problem. It is possible that the names contain a hidden character or space that
// caused the proble. More investigation will need to be done to find a better resolution to this 
// strange problem. On 8/1/13 - It was found that the two Parameters AvgGhostValAsSir77 and MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77
// have a trailing space to thier names in the Postgres database and that's why these two parameters
// were NOT working. It was decided instead of having IQAF people modify the database that the two
// statements using the LIKE will remain in place. The file was modified on this date 8/1/13.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// only take values that actually get reported on the dashboard
// this list comes from the "MeasurementNames" table
foreach ($measurementIDs as $mid){
    if($mid[0] == "AvgGhostValAsSir77") $qry .= '(("ParameterName" LIKE ' . "'%AvgGhostValAsSir77%'" . ') AND ("TargetName"=' . "'" . $mid[1] . "')) OR "; 
    else if($mid[0] == "MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77") $qry .= '(("ParameterName" LIKE ' . "'%MaxNegGhostingValAsSir77%'" . ') AND ("TargetName"=' . "'" . $mid[1] . "')) OR "; 
    else $qry .= '(("ParameterName"=' . "'" . $mid[0] . "'" . ') AND ("TargetName"=' . "'" . $mid[1] . "')) OR ";
}    
$qry = substr ($qry, 0, -4);
$qry .= ") ";

if (isset($captureTime)){   // used for incremental updates
    $qry .= ' AND ("CaptureTime">' . "'" . $captureTime . "')";
}
// steve invalid reading code is -99999. 
$qry .= ' AND ("ParameterValues"."ParameterValue" != -99999) ORDER BY "PrintSampleID", "MeasurementID"';

$actionString = '$action';

$qryCreate = "CREATE TABLE #tmpMeasurementTable (TestGUID uniqueidentifier, 
            IQAFid uniqueidentifier, pqID int, MeasurementID int,
            EvaluationDate datetime, EvaluatorID int, 
            TestUnitID int, TestUnitCountID int,
            TestPatternID int, ColorID int,
            TargetID int, ParameterID int,
            ParameterValue real)
            CREATE TABLE #MergeOutput (ActionType nvarchar(10))";
//start putting data into measurement tables
$qry1a= "INSERT INTO #tmpMeasurementTable VALUES ";
//put 1a data in MeasurementData
$qry1b = "
    MERGE INTO MeasurementData AS Target
    USING #tmpMeasurementTable AS Source 
    ON Target.pqID=Source.pqID 
        AND Target.MeasurementID=Source.MeasurementID  
        AND Target.TargetID=Source.TargetID  
        AND Target.ParameterID=Source.ParameterID 
        AND Target.TestPatternID=Source.TestPatternID 
        AND Target.IQAFMeasurementID=Source.IQAFid  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Target.ParameterValue = Source.ParameterValue,
                Target.TestUnitID=Source.TestUnitID, 
                Target.TestUnitCountID=Source.TestUnitCountID,
                Target.EvaluationDate=Source.EvaluationDate,  
                Target.EvaluatorID=Source.EvaluatorID  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (TestGUID, IQAFMeasurementID, pqID, 
                MeasurementID, EvaluationDate, EvaluatorID, 
                TestUnitID, TestUnitCountID, TestPatternID, ColorID,
                TargetID, ParameterID, ParameterValue)
        VALUES (Source.TestGUID, Source.IQAFid, Source.pqID, 
                Source.MeasurementID, Source.EvaluationDate, Source.EvaluatorID, 
                Source.TestUnitID, Source.TestUnitCountID,
                Source.TestPatternID, Source.ColorID, 
                Source.TargetID, Source.ParameterID, Source.ParameterValue)
    OUTPUT 
        $actionString INTO #MergeOutput;
        DROP TABLE #tmpMeasurementTable";

$qryOutput = "SELECT ActionType, COUNT(ActionType)AS [count] FROM #MergeOutput GROUP BY ActionType";
$qryCleanup = "DROP TABLE #MergeOutput";

$qry1c = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#MergeOutput') AND xtype='U')
            DROP TABLE #MergeOutput
    CREATE TABLE #MergeOutput (ActionType nvarchar(10))
    SELECT TestIndex AS TestID, TestID AS TestNumber, MeasurementData.TestGUID, pqID, TestUnitID, TestUnitCountID, TestPatternID,
  ColorID, MeasurementData.MeasurementID, TargetID, ParameterID,
  CAST(ROUND(AVG(ParameterValue*Multiplier), 2)AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Value
  INTO #tmpTable
  FROM MeasurementData
  LEFT JOIN Measurements ON Measurements.MeasurementID=MeasurementData.MeasurementID 
  LEFT JOIN Tests ON Tests.TestGUID=MeasurementData.TestGUID AND Tests.PiggybackID IS NULL 
  WHERE MeasurementData.TestGUID='" . $TestGUID . "' AND pqID>=" . $startPQid . " AND pqID<=" .$endPQid;


if (isset($captureTime))    // used for incremental updates
{
    $qry1c .= " AND EvaluationDate>'" . makeDateTime($captureTime) . "'";
}

$qry1c .= " GROUP BY TestIndex, TestID, MeasurementData.TestGUID, pqID, TestUnitID, TestUnitCountID, TestPatternID,
  ColorID, MeasurementData.MeasurementID, TargetID, ParameterID
  ORDER BY ColorID, TestPatternID, TestUnitCountID, MeasurementData.MeasurementID, TargetID, ParameterID;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS rows INTO #DashboardRows;";

//put temporary table in dashboard table
$qry1d = ";
    MERGE INTO DashboardData AS Target
    USING #tmpTable AS Source
    ON Target.pqID=Source.pqID 
        AND Target.MeasurementID=Source.MeasurementID  
        AND Target.TargetID=Source.TargetID  
        AND Target.ParameterID=Source.ParameterID 
        AND Target.TestPatternID=Source.TestPatternID 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Target.ParameterValue=Source.Value,
                Target.TestUnitID=Source.TestUnitID, 
                Target.TestUnitCountID=Source.TestUnitCountID 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (TestGUID, pqID, 
                MeasurementID, 
                TestUnitID, TestUnitCountID, TestPatternID, ColorID,
                TargetID, ParameterID, ParameterValue,
                TestNumber, TestIndex)
        VALUES (Source.TestGUID, Source.pqID,
                Source.MeasurementID,
                Source.TestUnitID, Source.TestUnitCountID,
                Source.TestPatternID, Source.ColorID, 
                Source.TargetID, Source.ParameterID, Source.Value, 
                Source.TestNumber, Source.TestID)
     OUTPUT 
        $actionString INTO #MergeOutput;
    DROP TABLE #tmpTable";
```

The queries get executed like this:

```
 $result = $ms_conn->query($qry1c);     $recordCount = $ms_conn->fetchOne
 ("SELECT rows FROM #DashboardRows");   //dataLog ("OLAP database " .
 $recordCount . " records to process", true);   $result =
 $ms_conn->query($qry1d); dataLog ("end dashboard query");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look at the intermediate tables, remove the first character `#` from the table names. This will make the tables non temporary, as SQL Server ha the convention that a table is temporary if its name starts with this character. You might also want to remove the `drop table` statements from the code. Then you can just look into these intermediate tables like into any other table.

Of course, to be able to re-run the code, you would have to drop the tables manually.

Comment: Thanks @FrankPl! We'll give it a try.  If we want to drop the tables manually, do we need to go to a new sql query and type, for example, "DROP TABLE #MergeOutput"  ?

Comment: @Michele Yes, probably omitting the '#'. But you can also do this via the GUI in Management Studio: In Object Explorer (normally in the left), open your database, open the "tables" node, select the table (you may have to select the "tables" node an hit F5 to  refresh the table list to see it), and hit the Del key. Then confirm the deletion.

Comment: I'm having a tough time deciding which # to delete since there are so many and they are used in the next statement, so if I delete the #, it will make the rest of the code not work.

Comment: @Michele Just delete all '#'s.

Comment: Won't that make it so the next query fails because it can't find the table?  If I remove the #'s, where is the table that it's using?

Comment: @Michele Well, if you omit the `#` in the `CREATE TABLE`, you have to omit it in the `MERGE ... USING` as well, as the table name is just different. It just has to be consistent.

Comment: I just thought I'd add this tidbit.  I took away the # for tmpTable and tmpMeasurementTable but when I ran the code I didn't see it in the SQL database.  Even after we refreshed.  Then my co-worker figured out that it would appear if we closed the datase and re-opened it.  All set!  Thanks!

Comment: @Michele If you're watching for new tables in SQL Management Studio, you have to refresh the `Tables` branch of the tree or higher to see new tables.