# SQL Merge Error : The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a source table

```
select 54371 Id, 'foo' [CreateBy], '2016-10-24 09:29:18.548'[CreateDate], 'foo'[UpdateBy],  '2016-10-24 09:29:18.548'[UpdateDate], 'E'[MT], 185761[MID], 3[BGID]
union
select 54372, 'foo', '2016-10-24 09:30:18.548', 'foo',  '2016-10-24 09:30:18.548',  'E', 185761, 2
```

and a target table

```
select 54379 Id, 'foo' [CreateBy], '2016-10-24 09:29:18.548'[CreateDate], 'foo'[UpdateBy],  '2016-10-24 10:29:18.548'[UpdateDate], 'E'[MT], 185761[MID], 3[BGID]
```

What I want is to match based on MT, MID and

1. Insert if not exists
2. update if BGID matches
3. delete if BGID does not matches

When I use SQL Merge Statement I get error

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.`

My Merge is like this

```
MERGE   
  FooBar AS target
USING
(
SELECT
E.[Id],
E.[CreateBy],
E.[CreateDate],
E.[UpdateBy],
E.[UpdateDate],
E.[MT],
E.[MID],
E.[BGID]
FROM @FooBar E
) AS source
ON
source.MID = target.MID
AND source.MT = target.MT
WHEN MATCHED and target.[BGID] = source.[BGID] THEN
UPDATE SET
target.[UpdateBy] = Source.[UpdateBy]
,target.[UpdateDate] = Source.[UpdateDate]
When Matched and source.BGID <> target.BGID THEN
DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT([CreateBy]
,[CreateDate]
,[UpdateBy]
,[UpdateDate]
,[MT]
,[MID]
,[BGID])
VALUES
(
Source.[CreateBy]
,Source.[CreateDate]
,Source.[UpdateBy]
,Source.[UpdateDate]
,Source.[MT]
,Source.[MID]
,Source.[BGID]
);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Removed `MySQL` tag since question is related to `SQL Server`. Please don't use irrelevant tags while posting a question.

Comment: Check this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434028/issues-with-sql-server-merge-statement

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are joining the tables on `ON source.MappingId = target.MappingId`.

In your data sample, there are more than 1 row with same `MappingId = 185761`.
So here you got:

> A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times.

You need to specify some **unique column combination** to join the `source` and the `target` tables.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my solution! :)

Comment: You don't need to specify unique column combinations if you use `GROUP BY` clause instead of `ON`

Comment: @Harvey What do you mean? You can use `group by` f.e. in source part, but anyway in the `merge` statement you will need `on` to specify merge select condition.

Comment: future readers: OP edited the question, so `MappingId` is now `MID`.

Comment: but for me I need multiple update for each repeated row, what i have to do?

Comment: To use MERGE each row should be unique, otherwise you can use UPDATE to change a bunch of rows at once. And what is "multiple update"? @lady

Comment: I meant multiple records from source update one record in destination, like accumlating value by many records, clear?

Comment: Custom script only.

Comment: For instance you have 3 rows in source, that should update 1 row in target. You need to run onevmerge only with 1 row from source, then second, then third etc. So basically you need to divide source table onto many tables with unique riws for each row in a target and run merges one by one.